# change the variables of a function with two outputs in a loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a function which gives me two outputs, i need to use it in a for loop to create different variables, and i want to use them later in next loops. so i need to change their name during the for loop when they are created.
something like this:

```
for l=1:L
    [A(l),B(l)] = function(l);
end
```

how can i do this so i could have A1,A2,... or B1,B2,.... 
thanks

Comment: So, what is the problem exactly? Have you tried cell-array: `[A{l} B{l}]`?

Comment: +1 cell array. Making different named variables (a1,a2 etc), will only make life more difficult for yourself later.

Comment: I have to use the A and B from the previous level for the next one. i want to have their name so i could use the term A(l-1) or B(l-1). i don't want to use cell array, it will cause me some trouble in the next commends

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to [use cell arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714410/shai) you can use [structure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) with dynamic field names:

```
for l = 1:L
    afn = sprintf('A%d', l ); % field name for first output
    bfn = sprintf('B%d', l ); % field name for second output
    [s.(afn) a.(bfn)] = func( l );
end

fieldnames( s ); % see all created variable names
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example that you can modify to your needs.

```
function main // because we need to call `func`

L = 5; // max num of iterations

for l = 1:L

    // replace `func` with the name of your function
    eval(['[A' num2str(l) ', B' num2str(l) '] = func(' num2str(l) ')'])

end

end

// your function goes here
function [s, c] = func(x)

s = x*x;
c = s*x;

end
```

Comment: -1 for using the evil `eval`. See [tips](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) for reasons why it is best to avoid `eval`.